# mySQL : select all column with limit substract one from count

Tags: mysql, limit

I need to select 9 rows out from 10 of user booking DB by having this code but no luck:

```
select count(id) as ids, * from booking_db where date between '2012-10-01' and '2012-10-10' limit 0, ids-1
```

I googled, someone suggested `LIMIT 1,9999999` <- this also comes up with 9 results but not the first row which is needed to be enlisted on the invoice. I expect the result of day 1 to 9. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

because you have set the limit 0 that why there is nothing you can use the `limit 9` to select 9

Comment: What if I have more than 10 and want to select the rows by all rows-1?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select 9 columns, you have to specify the column names in your select and *not use the asterisk*:

```
SELECT count(id) as ids, col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM booking_db
WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-10'
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, ...
```

Note that you also have to group by these columns as well (with a `GROUP BY clause), but I trust this is not a problem.